# jQuery appendTo next or find

Tags: jquery

I have this two divs and I want to move the .a's inside .u-list.

.a 1,2,3 in the first .u-list,

4,5,6 in the second .u-list

```
<div id='div-1'>
   <div class='u-list'></div>
   <div class='a'>1</div>
   <div class='a'>2</div>
   <div class='a'>3</div>
</div>

<div id='div-2'>
   <div class='u-list'></div>
   <div class='a'>4</div>
   <div class='a'>5</div>
   <div class='a'>6</div>
</div>
```

This is what I've tried:

```
$( 'div[id^="div-"]' ).each(function( index ) {
   $(this).find(".a").detach().appendTo($(this).find('.u-list'));
})
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It does not work for two reasons.

1. your original mark up is invalid in the first place, you cannot place `<li>`s outside an `<ul>`
2. add `"` to your selector: `$( 'div[id^="div-"]' )`

Comment: The markup is incorrect but it does not mean that he can move the elements, anyway the browser renders the elements. About the selector I think that the " is not needed because the code is working ok for me.

Comment: I solved my problem. It was because the .u-list was actually a class from another jQuery and it was loaded after my script. So actually the class u-list didn't exist.